# Numpy.cov generating matrix with negative det

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance, normal-distribution

I am trying to compute pdf of D-dim normal distribution using code like

```
a = 1.0 / math.sqrt(np.linalg.det(sigma))
inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
dif = x - mu
return a * math.exp(-np.dot(np.dot(dif, inv), dif) / 2)
```

where `sigma` is generated by `numpy.cov`.

However, there shows an error

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

and I find out that the determinant is negative.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Please provide the data you are working with, or at leas a sample of it.

Answer (score 0):

One common pitfall is computing the covariance along the data dimension instead of the sample dimension. From the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html):

> Each row of `m` represents a variable, and each column a single observation of all those variables

So, make sure your covariance matrix matches the dimensionality of your data and if not, give this a try:

```py
np.cov(x.T)
```